# Oracle format integers and float 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to format

```
if integer: then integer
if float: then float.xx(2 precision)
```

I have a column with values that are either integer or float. I want the output to be comma separated too. I have been using following line.

```
TO_CHAR(number,FM999G999G999D99) "Output",
```

I am getting output like

```
INPUT
--------
1234
1234.56
--------

TO_CHAR(INPUT,FM999G999G999D99) "Output",


OUTPUT
--------
1234.
1234.56
--------
```

My desired output is

```
OUTPUT
--------
1234
1234.56
--------
```

I don't want '.' at the end of integer.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the below

```
      TO_CHAR(INPUT,DECODE(INPUT,TRUNC(INPUT),'FM999G999G999','FM999G999G999D99'))
```

Comment: This solution misses the 3 trailing spaces for integers.

Comment: can you please elaborate how this three trailing spaces matter for integers

Comment: @wolφi - I think you are confused here. The output is all strings, which in most front ends are left aligned. What you think you are seeing in the OP’ desired output is an optical illusion, that the output is properly aligned at the decimal point.  It is not.

Comment: @psaraj12 you are right, I was thinking right aligned for some reason.

Comment: @wolφi it is ok the logic is for integers the decimals are ignored